# Function parameter type for http/https package?

Tags: typescript

Instead of just "any". e.g.

```
app.all('*', (request: any, response: any) => {}
```

I would like to have a better parameter checking. I have tried

```
request: ClientRequest, request: IncomingMessage
```

but none could be resolved. What kind of "import" statement do I need for standard HTTP/HTTPS for parameter typing?

Thanks

Comment: You could `import * as http from "http"` and then use `http`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: Let me provide it as an answer then so as to help others too.

Answer (score 1):

The types are `Express.Request` and `Express.Response` and work with both http / https.

## More

You can skip the annotations and TypeScript will infer it for you :

```
app.all('*', (request, response) => {})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `import * as http from "http"` and then use `http`